# Сериализация ObservableCollection<> и сохранение изменений в файл

Tags: c#, uwp

Подскажите как мне правильно организовать `ObservableCollection<T>`, которая является `ItemsSource` для `ListView`, при изменении (добавлении или удалении элементов) которой происходила бы сериализация этой коллекции и запись в файл. В таком коде, который хотя бы более-менее работает есть одна большая проблема: в модификаторе `get{}` используется асинхронная операция, а это значит что она ставится в фон, а `get` возвращает `null`, так как возвращение происходит до сериализации. Может кто с таким сталкивался, чтобы любое изменение коллекции сразу записывать в файл? И еще вопрос, если класс статический, то он же не должен будет быть подобранным сборщиком мусора. Может можно просто единоразово инициализировать коллекцию из файла и потом вносить изменения при закрытии программы?

```
public static class SavedTracksData
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<TrackListTemplate> list;

        public static ObservableCollection<TrackListTemplate> TrackList
        {
            get
            {
                GetTrackListData();
                if (list != null)
                {
                    return list;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ObservableCollection<TrackListTemplate>();
                }
            }
        }
        public static async void GetTrackListData()
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("SavedTracksData.dat");
                using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<TrackListTemplate>));
                    list = (ObservableCollection<TrackListTemplate>)serializer.Deserialize(stream.AsStream());
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch { }

        }
        public static async void SaveTrackListData()
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("SavedTracksData.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<TrackListTemplate>));
                    serializer.Serialize(stream.AsStream(), list);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Выполнять асинхронную операцию в геттере — ужасно. Просто никогда так не делайте.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы сохранение не положить в сеттер? Меняется коллекция целиком - сразу записывается. Плюс у `ObservableCollection` есть событие изменения коллекции. Можно подписаться на него и перезаписывать файл каждый раз при любом изменении коллекции, а не только при полном пересоздании.

`stream.Dispose()` не нужен, т.к. у вас используется `using`

Comment: Подписку делать в конструкторе статического класса? Туда же вставить инициализацию списка? Просто выходит ошибка null из-за того, что асинхронная задача идет в фоне и не успела загрузить данные, а уже return возвращает список.